# When does the while(1) loop break?

Tags: c++

I'm asking for help in explaining a very simple piece of code from an example of using the Adafruit_HTU21DF_Library library.

```
Adafruit_HTU21DF htu = Adafruit_HTU21DF();

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   Serial.println("HTU21D-F test");

   if (!htu.begin()) {
     Serial.println("Couldn't find sensor!");
     while(1);
   }
}
```

If the condition in the if statement turns out to be TRUE, then it seems to me that the program execution will forever be stuck in the while(1) loop.

But I don't think the authors could have allowed the program to behave like this. Therefore, we can assume that the while(1) loop will break at some point. Due to what? Is it possible that behind the neat short program we see is hidden a more complex assembly language structure that would explain the behavior that is not entirely obvious (at least to me)?

I would also like to add that my original question was caused by the fact that in other libraries initialization of sensors is performed slightly differently. Here's an example:

```
while (!bmp280_init(&bmp280, &bmp280.params)) {
size = sprintf((char *)Data, "BMP280 initialization failed\n");
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, Data, size, 1000);
HAL_Delay(2000);
}
```

As you can see, possible subsequent access to a non-working sensor is also prevented here, however, there is a technical difference: the sensor is given the opportunity to prepare in case of unavailability. It was this difference that confused me: I did not expect that in other libraries, even at the first access to an unready sensor, further execution of the program in fact be interrupted.

Comment: Your suspicions are correct. The `while` loop will run until our sun explodes, a few billion years from now.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Infinite loops without side effects are UB, so it might not run at all.

Comment: Assuming this is code for a microprocessor, if it cant find the sensor it cant continue so it just idles the microprocessor in the while, until you reset the processor.

Comment: You're really going to have to read documentation for your compiler (and possibly host system). In standard C++, an infinite loop with no side effects gives undefined behaviour - so looping forever, not looping at all, or looping until some (possibly system dependent) event occurs are all equally correct outcomes. If someone  *deliberately* wrote code like this then, hopefully, they knew what the specific outcome would be with a particular compiler and target system - and documented that fact. Pessimistically, they may have believed they knew, but got it wrong - and didn't document either.

Comment: For safety and robustness, never use a forever loop.  Always have your loops limited by an iteration count.  This will ensure that your loop doesn't run forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while(1);` is used to avoid continuing if a error occurs.

If you run a debugger you can stop at this position and look for the cause of the error.

If you don't want this behavior: substitute `while(1)` with `return ERROR_VALUE` or use another way to inform the user about the missing sensor. And inform the other code, which tries to read from sensor, that this is not possible.

Comment: Relying on undefined behaviour to do something like that is ... a bad idea.

Comment: The issue here is that it is for an Arduino, and once `setup()` is done it will continue into `loop()` (which is compiler-defined to be an infinite loop). This may be a problem if the loop body relies on the sensor being present - maybe it was wired wrong, and proceeding blind will cause the microprocessor to start turning on GPIO pins in a manner that will damage the incorrectly wired peripherals.  Also `setup()` and `loop()` are defined by the Arduino compiler to be of `void` type so `return ERROR_VALUE` is not going to work regardless.

Comment: @Frodyne most people are aware of that. This doesn't mean using UB is a good idea. For this scenario I would just make code in `loop` which does something else, for example flashing some diode to indicate an error (anything what would show there is a problem to a user).

Comment: @MarekR Like `Serial.println("Couldn't find sensor!");`? (I would recommend `while (1) delay(-1);`, but [many](https://search.arduino.cc/search?tab=reference&q=%22while+%281%29%3B%22) [existing](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22while+%281%29%3B%22) pieces of Arduino code rely on this so maybe it's not UB with an Arduino compiler?)

Comment: @Artyer UB means anything can happen. So it may work as desired. Problem is that this kind of UB end result depends on compiler and its options. So even tweaking compiler options can lead to different behavior of final code (removing this loop is quite common).

Comment: I thank everyone who responded to my question. Yes, indeed, there is no reason to assume that if the sensor is not ready, the endless loop will ever end. Consequently, as rightly noted, program execution will not go further, but will stop at this point, preventing the possible negative consequences of further access to a non-working sensor. It is interesting that in libraries for other sensors, for example, BMP280, AHT21, a slightly different design is used: while (1) delay(10); It seems that in this case, instead of 10 ms, any delay can be determined.